# Screen tearing using Firefox and Chrome at full screen

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, screen-tearing

About ten minutes ago, I came back to my computer and noticed that my screen seemed to be "tearing" to the right, comparable to the wind effect in GIMP. This was mostly on the edges of the Chrome browser window I had open, and over text in the window, but I noticed it over text in an IRC chat I had opened too.

Immediately, I suspected my video card was dying, but I noticed it wasn't happening on my top and bottom panels (Ubuntu Linux). As soon as I closed out of the Chrome window, it stopped. The IRC chat was fine too. I opened Chrome again, and it appeared instantly! I minimized the browser, and the IRC chat was fine. I then maximized the browser in the background, and the tearing returned, interrupting the chat as well. I closed out again.

This time, I switched users. I opened Chrome. It was fine. I loaded a YouTube video, and within about two to three minutes, the tearing began again. I figured it was browser-based, so I opened Firefox. There was nothing for a while, then out of the blue, the tearing was now happening on another browser. I exited fullscreen, and scaled the window down. The tearing stopped. I maximized. The tearing reappeared. Right as I type this message, I can maximize the page, and there will be no tearing, but I can guarantee it will show back up if I leave the window open and maximized for too long.

What could be the problem? I also opened up a dozen of different programs. None of those tear. It seems to be entirely browser-based. Here's a picture of the edge of the screen with the Wind effect applied to it in GIMP. It looked pretty much like this.

[image]

Comment: run a stability test on your gpu. this is not tearing.

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading to Firefox 3.5.

I had the same problem and suspected it was the new graphics card I had just installed. However, I looked around and found a lot of people having this problem with Firefox 4, so I installed Firefox 3.5 and now the tearing is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Is it related to this?  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/780094